# converting a file to list or string in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having a bit of an issue taking a text file and converting it into a list or string.

Say I have "blah.txt" which holds:

```
3 + 4
```

Now I want to call that file which I know can be done by

```
(define in (open-input-file "blah.txt"))
```

Where do I take it from here?

Comment: The leading quote in the question doesn't look right.  I expected `(define in (open-input-file "blah.txt"))`.  Please confirm.

Comment: Oh yeah, My mistake. didn't mean to put that quotation mark. It should've read (define in(open-input-file "blah.txt"))

Comment: Ok, good.  I'll edit the question accordingly without the quote.  Good luck!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the [`file->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=file-%3Elist#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3elist%29%29) function or [`file->lines`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=file-%3Estring#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3estring%29%29), which should do what you want in Racket. That is, something like `(file->lines "blah.txt")` will give you a list of lines from the file. More generally, look at the [guide entry](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/i_o.html) on I/O.

Comment: For a generator, use `in-lines`

Answer (score 6):

Given a file name, [file->string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3estring%29%29) loads the file and returns the content as a string.

Comment: This link is dead.  Consider updating it if you can.